# can't access jenkins configuration file dir

Tags: windows, jenkins, directory

I would like to know why, after running on my console:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

and going after the installation process, I can't access the jenkins configuration dir  in the same dir as the war file. Where should I look this dir in case I wanna backup ?.

Answer (score 1):

Default location for Jenkins on a Windows machine is `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\.jenkins`. You can specify this location by specifying `JENKINS_HOME`, like this:

```
java -DJENKINS_HOME=C:\path\to\jenkins\home -jar jenkins.war
```